# Best UX options for table cell with multiple items

Tags: tables, filter, data-tables

I am trying to see if this is a practical and good way of handling this problem.

[image: UI mockup]

We have a table with a list of users. Users have units that are assigned to them. A user can have multiple units. Generally, most users have up to two units, but they can have more.

The top is a search filter that applies labels such as "Unit". Then you can specify a specific unit such as "College of Engineering" which would show users associated with this unit. Rows can have variable heights based on the number of units a user is assigned to.

Does the attached mockup make sense? Is there a better way of handling this? Would multiple users listed with a single unit make sense or is that bad UX practice?

Thanks in advance for everyone's assistance and information.

Comment: The relationship between the question and the title isn't obvious. Can you clarify the question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design is fine since variable height is an aesthetic concern. All the necessary information is immediately available and easy to read. You can replace the line breaks in the unit column with commas to minimize the row height used.

> Would multiple users listed with a single unit make sense or is that bad UX practice?

No, this won't make sense. Your filter shouldn't change the *shape* of the data in the table, it should only select the rows that are displayed.

Comment: Hi Andre, the mockup designed is assuming a filter hasn't been applied. Therefore, multiple rows could have variable height based on how many units they are associated to. That being said, is this mockup still a good UX pattern? Are there any other options?

Comment: @bobbyo23 I see. I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you for the quick update. That makes sense. I don't really see a better solution to this problem. On a side note, I also posted this question here that maybe you can take a look at: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/99923/does-ellipsis-button-work-on-left-or-right-of-table-row

Answer (score 0):

For just a items I like the presentation you have
Can center or top align

For many items and running out of space can use a pull down
I should have used an example with more than one selected

[image: pull down]

Can also just concatenate with ;